# Rails 3, Model Methods / Calculated Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am dealing with numerous calculations to bring various values within a model to a simple TRUE or FALSE. Problem is, these calculations are pretty intense and not something I want to create a long, hard to follow SQL statement for. I'd rather just have the entire calculation within a method that the model could check for when returning records.

I've tried numerous ways to accomplish this, and when looking up other similar feats, others push newbs like me to SQL which might serve most purposes but will not serve mine as the calculations being done are somewhat external to the model.

Model:

```
class Quality < ActiveRecord::Base
...
def passed_inspection
   [code that calculates based on values in model]
end
```

Controller:

```
@records = Quality.where('passed_inspection = true')
```

View:

```
Did pass inspection?: <%= record.passed_inspection %>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the calculations you are trying?

Comment: What is the problem you need help with? If you do not want a long SQL statement use code a model's method. If you do not want to put the calculation code in the model's class then create controller helper method that takes as input the model and returns TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @MatteoMelani I already do have the calculations represented as view helpers, but I also need to pull records based on pass/fail. For example, I have a view that outputs only failed records into a table.

Comment: @ScottJShea, I can't really post much of it because it contains some of my client's privileged formulas, etc. The calculations themselves aren't really overwhelming or difficult. They are a series of Excel evaluations _transcribed_ into Ruby. I just can't see how they could be turned into an easy-to-read SQL statement. I'd rather be able to simplify for myself, but for others who may get involved later on.

Comment: @Nicodemus I follow you... looks like coderates helped anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like the solution to your problem would be to use a **Scope** with a **Class Method** to help clean up your model. Essentially you would set up your model like this:

```
class Quality < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.passed_inspection
        # Code that does your calculations
    end

    scope :passed, passed_inspection() # This needs to be below the function above
end
```

Then you could get this data by calling it like this

```
@records = Quality.passed
```

There is a rails cast about this problem if you need any more information: [RailsCast #215 Advanced Queries](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast)

Edit: Fixed some terrible grammar

Comment: If I could upvote you yet, I would! Thanks a lot. This is basically what I needed.