# Should I save a Model calculation as an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model

I have an app that enables a user to create a new room using a form to enter name, description, length, and width.  Each room created becomes a new record and the app calculates the 'size' of the room as 'length' * 'width'.  This is a simple app that I'm playing with to learn Rails but I may take it further to have a collection of rooms form a house, with some total 'size' of each house.
My question relates to the 'size' value and how that should be integrated into the app.  I initially thought that the user should see the value of 'size' right away on the form, but shelved that once it appeared that Ajax may be required.  I moved the 'size' method calculation from the view to the model to conform to "fat model, skinny controller" concept and I now show the 'size' in the 'index' view, leaving the 'new' view purely for entering data.

I initially set up the model to include length, width and size.  See migration for the Room model:

**20150118183743_create_rooms.rb**

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :length
      t.integer :width
      t.integer :size

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Should I save 'size' for each record to the database?  I've read that it shouldn't be necessary to save calculations as an attribute to the model.  Presumably, the app should handle that?  What's the correct way to think about this?
My 'index' view calculates & returns max 'length' and 'width', but I run into an error when I try to calculate the max 'size'.  I have a calculation (i.e., method) for this in model but it appears to be wrong.  Any suggestions?
Below are relevant code:

**room.rb**

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name,    presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 },
                                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :length, :width,  presence: true,
                                numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                                less_than_or_equal_to: 1000,
                                greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }

    def size
        size = length * width
    end

    def max_room
        size.max
    end

end
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

    def index
    @rooms = Room.all
  end

  def create
        @room = Room.new(user_params)  
        if @room.save                   #a boolean, if able to save the instance
            flash[:success] = "You created a new Room!!"
            redirect_to @room   #we send the user to the room
        else
            render 'new'            #so we want to render the new template 
        end 
  end

    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:room).permit(:name, :description, :length,
                                         :width, :size)
        end


end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Rooms') %>

<h1>All rooms</h1>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row column-md-7">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Length (ft.) </th>
                    <th class="text-right">Width (ft.) </th>
                    <th class="text-right">Size (sq.ft.) </th>
                    <th class="text-center">Delete? </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

              <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
                <tr>
                  <td> <%= link_to room.name, room %> </td>
                  <td> <%= room.description %> </td>
                  <td class="text-right"> <%= room.length %> </td>
                  <td class="text-right"> <%= room.width %> </td>
                  <td class="text-right"> <%= room.size %> </td>
                  <td class="text-center"> <%= link_to "delete", room, method: :delete, 
                        data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="alert alert-info">
      The model contains <%= pluralize(Room.count, "room") %> in total.  
      The max length is <%= Room.maximum('length') %>.
      The max width is <%= Room.maximum('width') %>.

    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried showing 'size' by adding

```
The max size is <%= Room.max_room %>
```

but that returned an error.

**new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "New Room")  %>
<h1>The Rooms page </h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@room) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

            <%= f.label :name %>    
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :description %>
            <%= f.text_area :description %>

            <%= f.label :length, "Length (ft.)" %>
            <%= f.number_field :length %>

            <%= f.label :width, "Width (ft.)" %>
            <%= f.number_field :width %>

            <%= f.submit "Create my room", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @room.name)  %>
<h1>The "<%= @room.name %>" page </h1>
<h2>This page contains the show action associated with the 
    Rooms page </h2>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Length (ft.) </th>
                    <th class="text-right">Width (ft.) </th>
                    <th class="text-right">Size (sq.ft.) </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> <%= @room.name %> </td>
            <td> <%= @room.description %> </td>
            <td class="text-right"> <%= @room.length %> </td>
            <td class="text-right"> <%= @room.width %> </td>
            <td class="text-right"> <%= @room.size %> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<%= link_to "Create a new room", new_room_path, class: "btn btn btn-primary" %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root                  'static_pages#home'
  get 'home'            =>  'static_pages#home'
  get 'calculations'    => 'static_pages#calculations'
  get 'help'            =>  'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'           => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'new_room'        =>  'rooms#new'
  get 'rooms'           =>  'rooms#index'
  resources :rooms
end
```

I plan to use apps that will be heavy with numerical calculations so I want to get these fundamentals right.  I don't want the app's database to blow up if I'm saving too many calculations down when they should be done (perhaps) in a virtual environment.

So, to recap ....

1. Should a app calculation be saved to the database as an attribute to a new record?
2. What might be the correct calculation/method for 'size'?
3. If I want to perform a calculation on a calculated value, does that value first have to be saved as an attribute?

Comment: Have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571547/rails-3-model-methods-calculated-attributes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Never post a question with " that returned an error." Always quote the exact error message (but first remove any private text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `max_room` is wrong, since the `size` value is just a number, the max method is not defined on a number, but instead it should be called on an `Enumerable` of values. 
So `Room` should be implemented this way:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name,    presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 },
                                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive:    false }
    validates :length, :width,  presence: true,
                                numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                                less_than_or_equal_to: 1000,
                                greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }

    def size
        size = length * width
    end

    class << self
      # This is a class method, since it depends on all the rooms
      # not on a specific room 
      def max_size
          # This will delegate the calculation to the database
          select('MAX(length * width) AS max')[0]['max'];
      end
      # But, this will instantiate the records on memory before it makes the calculation
      # def max_room
      #    all.max{ |room| room.length * room.width }
      # end
      # This is a class method as well
      def max_room
        order('size DESC').first
      end
    end
end
```

> 1. Should a app calculation be saved to the database as an attribute to a new record?

If the attributes on which the calculated value depends will change frequently, in this case you should not save the calculated value, but rather calculate it every time you need it. But as I can see the length and the width of a room will not change, so the calculated value will need to be calculated once, and saved to be used when needed (e.g to calculate the max_size), so in this case you need to create an attribute `size` and calulate it when you create the record using a hook.

```
before_save :calculate_size

private
def calculate_size
   size = length * width
end
```

Comment: I think that you're spot on - the length and width will not change, so it seems to make sense to define a new attribute, especially since I'll be using 'size' for other features of the app.  As you can see from the "create_rooms.rb" migration above, the attribute exists. I'm just not using it yet.  Follow-up question: In room.rb, can I get rid of the 'size' method given your suggestion to go with 'calculate_size'?  Also, should I go with 'self.size = length * width'?  Would this create and save 'size' for a specific @room instance?

Comment: @TomShaw Yes, you can get rid of the `size` method, it has no sense now, the `@room.size` will get the saved value from the database. The assignment `size = length * width` will change the instance attribute `size`  but will not save it.The `before_save` hook, which run an instance method, will set the `size` attribute just before the instance is persisted to the database, and then all the changed attributes will be saved in one step.

Comment: I'm now able to  automatically calculate and save 'size' to the database. Great!  I'm still working on retrieving the room with the largest 'size' value.  I'm getting 'undefined method' error when I call the max_room method on the Room class.  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, `max_size` and `max_room` should be class methods, I put it in the comment but I defined it as an instance method. Ok I edited the answer, you should not get that `undefined method error`

Comment: I added the `max_room` method check the answer.